# Vue JS router & updating route content dynamically

Tags: javascript, vue-router, vue.js, vuejs2

I am currently creating a client-side Vue JS app using Vue Router. To give you a bit of history, the app loads a json file stored on the server to display data. Periodically this file gets updated and I want to re-load the file and update the view.

Ignoring the fetching of the data file (this bit is fine), when I set up a new data fetch and update the data using a base Vue example, it works as expected.

However, when I introduce Vue Router, the *visible* updated data does not display. Doing a `console.log` with the results (and even the router/vue instance) reveals the new data changes, but the HTML does not update to reflect the change.

I'm using Vue 2 (which is fairly new) and all the documentation/examples point to updating the data on a page navigation & using Node (which I am not doing).

I've mocked up a simple JS bin with the basic process of what i'm doing. You can see in the `newData` array, the name and percentage of the first item changes.

http://jsbin.com/jeseden/edit?js,output

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way of doing this is actually with `prop`s.

This is all detailed in the blog post I wrote on the topic:

https://www.liquidlight.co.uk/blog/article/building-a-vue-v2-js-app-using-vue-router/

With an example being found on [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/bikadol/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

You code is not working as in `ListingCompo` component, you are initialising the data, but it is not aware of later changes. To have the change reflected later as well, either you need to put watcher on the parent data, or simply have a computed property, which will change whenever your parent data will change.

```
var ListingCompo = {
    template: '#template',
    data: function () {
        return {            
        }
    },
    computed: {
      records(){
        return  this.$parent.records
     }      
   }
};
```

Working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/xagenohaqu/edit?html,js,console,output).